# how to use awk parameter in shell

Tags: bash, shell, awk, ssh, sh

I need to use `sh -c "command"` where command is an `awk` with variables, but I haven't been able to, anyone can help?

Here is an example:

I have a file with several lines, and want to print the number of the lines that match a mark. In this case I use `sh`, but I will need to use `ssh` also.

```
$ file=file.txt
$ mark="xxxx"
$ cat $file
name
surname
xxxx
phone
xxxx
more data
more more data
xxxx
continue data
$ sh -c "awk -v line=\"$mark\" '$0 == line {print NR}' $file"
$ awk -v line="$mark" '$0 == line {print NR}' $file
3
5
8
```

The first run with `sh` returns nothing. The second run without `sh` runs ok.

==== more clarification

I have a function "execmd" that receives two parameters, first argument is a server name, the second is a string with a command

```
execmd ()
    {
    P_SERV="$1"
    P_CMD="$2"

    X_SERV=`hostname`
    if [ "$P_SERV" = "$X_SERV" ] ; then
   sh -c "$P_CMD"
    else
   ssh -n "$P_SERV" "$P_CMD"
    fi
    }
```

if i run:

```
xx=`execmd earth "awk -v line=\"$mark\" '\$0 == line {print NR}' $file"`; echo $xx
```

xx is empty

i put a echo inside execmd to see the command, and inside de function it translates the \$0 to bash
is there any other thing i have to add?
This is part of a mega script, where i have from one place monitor several ones, so if i have to run somthing locally i use sh, else ssh

Comment: Why do you need `sh -c ..`

Comment: you can try `sh -c "awk -v line=$mark '\$0 == line {print NR}' $file"`, but what is the point?

Comment: Replace `sh -c` with `echo` and the problem should be obvious.

Comment: Great! that helped! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enclose scripts with single quotes, not double, and then just open them up to expose shell variables if/when necessary in just that section of code:

```
$ sh -c 'awk -v line="'"$mark"'" '\''$0 == line {print NR}'\'' file'
3
5
8
```

To "include" single quotes in a single-quote delimited script is `'\''`, hence those strings around the awk script body instead of just `'` alone.

Here's an example of why not to use double quotes like in the comments under your question, lets say you just want to print `Eureka!` every time you match a line:

```
$ sh -c 'awk -v line="'"$mark"'" '\''$0 == line {print NR, "Eureka!"}'\'' file'
3 Eureka!
5 Eureka!
8 Eureka!
```

compared to (and note we're already having to escape `$0`):

```
$ sh -c "awk -v line=$mark '\$0 == line {print NR, "Eureka!"}' file"
-bash: !"}': event not found
```

There's other things to consider too and it gets even worse if `$mark` contains globbing characters.

Comment: Thanks @Ed Morton , could you please explain the difference between single quotes and double quotes? and in this case why do i have to put "'"$mark"'" instead of just "$mark"

Comment: A quick [google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash) produced https://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/1745001 and more. The reason you need `line"'"$mark"'"` is that you WANT to end up with `line="xxxx"` and to get to that point you need to open up your `sh-c` command line with a `'` then provide the variable quoted to avoid the shell from expanding globbing chars, etc. so `"$mark"` and then re-start the sh-c part with `'`. Hope that makes sense. Just count the quotes and think about what exactly each is starting/stopping/enclosing.